# MySQL: COUNT and GROUP BY to narrow search results

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, count, group-by

To simplify: I have a list of search results and a HTML form where the user can narrow the search results (they update on the fly using jQuery .load).

I was wondering how to best show the user, how many search results each change of the form will return, e.g. when the user checks a certain checkbox. And wanted to print this number directly next to it:

> [x] paramter 1 //this one is already checked
>  [ ] paramter 2
>   (2465 results)
>  [ ] paramter 3 (456 results)
>  [ ] paramter 4
>   (256 results)

Each time this list updates, the number should also update and `ORDER BY number of results DESC`...

The file `search.php` SELECTs the parameters from the database and prints the HTML form. Then I `.load` `search_update.php`, which reads and returns the actual results the user wants to see.

I hope it was explained understandable...

The thing is, I have multiple databases that are all joined in the query that is executed in `search_updated.php` and I tried to use COUNT and GROUP BY in this query, but I got lost...

- should I use it in this "main" query?
- or should I use it in the queries that print the HTML forms?
- should I make a new file for each HTML form and `.load` it like `search_update.php`?

Thank you very much in advance for any hint! :)

Image:

[image]

Comment: Do a search on faceted search, and you will get your answer.

Comment: @SativaNL: oh, OK.. thank you for this hint! So, you don't do this with a simple COUNT at all?